# Terminal stops every time a yes/no question appears

Tags: command-line, gksu

I have encountered a problem when using the terminal to install programs. Whenever a yes/no option like the one below appears, not just with this program, but with any I try, the terminal stops after I have selected yes and will do nothing. I have even left it on for 3 hours just in case it was going slow, but to no avail.

So my question is, what do I do to fix this or get around it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be due to the use of `gksudo`. It looks like it doesn't redirect the `stdin` to the launched process.

As explained in the [manual page of gksudo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksudo) :

> Their primary purpose is to run **graphical** commands that need root
>   without the need to run an X terminal emulator and using su directly.

It is not really intended to launch interactive console commands, `sudo` is designed for this kind of job.

Comment: thanks, now i get this instead, E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
what do i do about that?

Comment: Check this post out for fixing that issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/fixing-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock

Comment: Dont worry actually, figured it out on my own by using rm/var/lib/dpkg/lock then sudo dpkg --configure -a then runng sudo aptget for my program